# Multiple Virtual Hosts Subdomain 404s?

Tags: apache, centos, subdomain

I have an Apache Server running on a CentOS box running 3 websites using VirtualHosts.

The problem is, is when I go to a non-existent subdomain on the websites it always shows the files from Website #1. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Here's my httpd.conf: http://pastebin.com/5bDgrR2W (I've replaced my email and domain names)

Comment: You'll need to show an example of your config file I think. Sounds easy enough to fix if you can share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a default host configured, so whenever an unknown domain is called, the default config will be used.